# Where should I store secret strings on Node server?

Tags: node.js

Well, I've come with a problem. How can I store passwords, db url and important strings that should not go to my public version control?

I've come up with 3 solutions. The **first** works only on dev:

```
var config = require('./config');
var port = config.serverPort;
```

config.js

```
module.exports = {
  'serverPort' : '8182'
}
```

The **second** one should work both on dev and prod. But the config.js file was added on the *.gitignore* file, so it won't be upload to the server. When the server tries to require *config.js* and can't find it, it will throw an error.

```
var config = require('./config');
var port = process.env.PORT || config.serverPort;
```

The **third** is to use only process.env variables, but this only works on production. And, if I'm testing on local machine, I may need to paste my secret strings and remember to remove it before sending to the public version control.

So, what should I do?

Comment: It seems that a config file that contains secret settings and is not checked into version control is a common way of doing this.

Comment: But how should I manage this undefined require within my server? My server crash because it can't find the config.js file.

Comment: When you set up an installation, you manually create or copy the config.js file.  It's part of the local setup configuration that is specific to a given installation.  For example, the development DB may very well have a different path and password than the production DB (in fact, if this is a larger company, you won't even be allowed to know the production DB password).  So, you create an appropriate config file each time you set up a server that matches the configuration in that environment (paths, passwords, certificates, etc...).

Comment: Another common option are environment variables

Comment: FYI, you can check in a default config.js into the source control system that helps document what settings go in there, you just don't put any secrets in the source control version.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The common solution is to add a `config.js.example` file to version control (that contains empty/dummy values to document what's available).

Then you add `config.js` to .gitignore (or whatever suits your VCS).

To run your application you simply copy `config.js.example` to `config.js` and put in the proper values.

Of course the path to `config.js` can be taken from an environment variable to allow easily using different configs - but still, you wouldn't put the actual config files under version control (unless you have a separate private repo for config files etc)

It does make sense to always require a config file to exist. Even in development. While the default settings *may* be suitable, chances are good that many developers on your application want to configure things anyway or simply test things with non-default values.

Comment: So, it would be something like var config = require(process.env.configPath); ? Then I would have a config.js.example file that can be used as a empty file and will be added to VCS, while my config.js would only exist on devs computers.

Comment: Exactly. Well, almost. `config.js` would also exist on production machines, but never in VCS.

Comment: I use exactly this same approach; having a private repo for real production config values (like db user/password, AWS credentials, etc). In a build step I fetch these files via `git clone` before packaging the app. The not so good part is that if these values are not static all the time its hard to change them dynamically since it will require rebuilding and repackaging everything.

Comment: For more dynamic config values (example; our session secret often changes) I am planing in creating a central MySQL database that will store them, not sure if its a good idea though.

Comment: I'd say the good idea stopped being one when you mentioned MySQL ;) (use postgres)

Answer (score 7):

The `dotenv` package can be used to load configuration and secrets from a `.env` file into `process.env`. For production, the `.env` file doesn't have to exist.

Example:

```
require('dotenv').config();

const oauth2 = require('simple-oauth2').create({
  client: {
    id: process.env.TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY,
    secret: process.env.TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET
  }
});
```

.env file:

```
TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY=bMm...
TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET=jQ39...
```

.gitignore:

```
.env
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is my suggestion:

**1. Using a mix of file and env variables**

You can manage secret strings using a mix with config files and `process.env` variables.

You can do something like this:

```
var port = process.env.PORT || config.serverPort;
```

Since now, working with `docker` is the rule, you should try this one.

**2. Using a Sample**

You could add a `config.json.example` to your repo with an example of the variables you should define but here you will have to remember to change it when you deploy to production.

Just remember to add the real `config.json` to the `.gitignore` file.
This one is not my preferred but still an option.

Answer (score 2):

There's a node package that handles this very similar to the Ruby On Rails approach with their credential system: [schluessel](https://www.npmjs.com/package/schluessel)

It lets you save your secrets in an encrypted vault file and stores the key separately. This vauft file can be checked into your version control system, as long as you keep your key file secret.

You can create vault files for different NODE_ENVs.
If you surrender the key either via a key file or via an environment variable,
you can access your credentials very easily from within your app.