# How to set a Angular config var to set server address?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

How can I do some centralized solution to store strings on AngularJS? I've asked a similar [question regarding NodeJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33557425/where-should-i-store-secret-strings-on-node-server), but I don't know how to use the same approach to Angular as I've used to Node.

I've thought of 2 approaches:

**1 - Setting a Angular Constant**

```
app.constant('config',
  {
    serverUrl: 'http://localhost:8080'
  });
```

This is my actual solution, but it comes with the downside that I need to update my code with the server address every time I send the code to the cloud.

**2 - Using something like [Node's process.env](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_env)**

And I have no idea how.

**3 - Using something like require('./config.js')**

I'm thinking on the Node like approach. Don't know how.

Well, is there a good, effective way of accomplishing this?

Comment: we use the 1st approach, then we include the constants where ever we need them in our app

Comment: So, I need to update this line everytime I upload my come to Git? :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think that there is one right answer. I prefer your first approach:

```
app.constant('config',
  {
    serverUrl: 'http://localhost:8080'
  });
```

It is because I think about node.js backend and angular frontend as separete applications. For example I can add to node.js second version of api and connect other angular application (or event in another technology) to new api, but also use old angular app with previous api version. 
**In short in my opinion it is more flexible**

Edit:

> So, I need to update this line everytime I upload my come to Git

I don't add configuration file to repository. I create example config file which we add to repository. But actual config is ignored.

Edit2:

In one of mine project we use this module https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-ng-constant for build app.constant from config.json

Comment: This is nice, I'm looking it.

Answer (score 1):

This is how we switch the server url without rewriting it every time

```
  var hostname = window.location.hostname;
  if (hostname.indexOf("our.live.url") > -1) {
    usedEnvironment = availableEnvironments.LIVE;
  }  else if (hostname.indexOf("localhost") > -1) {
    usedEnvironment = availableEnvironments.LOCAL;
  } else {
    usedEnvironment = availableEnvironments.TEST;
  }

  switch (usedEnvironment) {
    case availableEnvironments.LIVE:
      angular.module('app')
        .value('apiHost', 'https://our.live.backend.com');
      angular.module('app')
        .value('IntercomConfig', {
          Enabled: true,
          AppId: ''
        });
      break;

    case availableEnvironments.TEST:
      angular.module('app')
        .value('apiHost', 'our.test.backend');
      angular.module('app')
        .value('IntercomConfig', {
          Enabled: false,
        });
      break;

    default:
      angular.module('app')
        .value('apiHost', 'http://localhost:8080');
      angular.module('app')
        .value('IntercomConfig', {
          Enabled: false,
        });
  }
```

Comment: Nice approach you have.